# GROUP BY based on dates and number of months

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by, date-difference

I have a PostgreSQL (many) table with monitoring data. The table contains an ID and Date column. Now I need to classify (group) all this monitoring data in strata (groups) of 6 months. So, in case a monitoring occurs more than 6 months later than the latest date, it is considered as a new monitoring and should be added to a new 'instance group'. If the monitoring occurred WITHIN 6 months of the latest date, it is considered as the same monitoring and added to the first instance group.

So basically I need to group the data based on ID and Date by counting the number of months between the Dates. All dates that are < 6 months in between go into one group (with the same ID). Now here is the difficulty: In case a Date is more than 6 months (> 6 months) ahead of the (second latest) previous date the row needs to be added to a new/seperate Date group (but of the same ID). Below the input and desired output:

[image]

[image]

Of course, I need to calculate specific results (SUMS/AVERAGES) for each monitoring instance group, but that should be fairly easy if I know how to create the groups. Any idea how I can do this best?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: please share your table script via https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it. I used LAG in a Window to calculate the distance (in days) between the dates. Then I used CASE to label the number of days into a monitoring group (eg. 2021-1 =  less then 180 days of difference, 2021-2 = between 181 and 360 days of difference, etc). Then I grouped the labels. Worked fine. Thanks for the help Slava!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate timestamps diff and compare the result like:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (EXTRACT(DAY from  NOW() - created_at) > 180) more_180_days
FROM monitor;
```

After that you can aggregate by this calculated column to rich desired result

[Test PostgreSQL here](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/132e77d10f6d6f71794818e7fce4e392/)